# Updating row of one table using rows of another table based on specific conditions

Tags: oracle, oracle-11g-r2, oracle-11g

I want to update `OFFICE_ID,OFFICE_TYPE` of `FA_SUBLEDGER_MST` table, by using `OFFICE_ID,OFFICE_TYPE` from `EMPLOYEE_MST` table based on following conditions:

```
EMPLOYEE_MST.SL_CODE = FA_SUBLEDGER_MST.SL_CODE
EMPLOYEE_MST.OFFICE_ID <> SL.OFFICE_ID
  OR EMPLOYEE_MST.OFFICE_TYPE <> SL.OFFICE_TYPE
AND EMPLOYEE_MST.OFFICE_TYPE != 'DHB'
```

I tried this query:

```
UPDATE FA_SUBLEDGER_MST sl
SET
  (sl.OFFICE_ID, sl.OFFICE_TYPE) =
  (SELECT 
       emp.OFFICE_ID, emp.OFFICE_TYPE
   FROM EMPLOYEE_MST emp
   WHERE emp.OFFICE_ID <> sl.OFFICE_ID
      OR emp.OFFICE_TYPE <> sl.OFFICE_TYPE
      AND sl.SL_CODE = emp.SL_CODE
      AND emp.OFFICE_TYPE != 'DHB')
WHERE sl.STATUS = 'A'
  AND EXISTS (SELECT 1
              FROM EMPLOYEE_MST emp
              WHERE emp.OFFICE_ID <> sl.OFFICE_ID
                 OR emp.OFFICE_TYPE <> sl.OFFICE_TYPE
                AND emp.SL_CODE = sl.SL_CODE  
                AND emp.OFFICE_TYPE != 'DHB');
```

But both gave this error:

> SQL Error: ORA-01427: single-row subquery returns more than one row
>   01427. 00000 - "single-row subquery returns more than one row"

And this:

```
UPDATE
  (SELECT em.OFFICE_ID emoffid,
    SL.OFFICE_ID sloffid,
    em.OFFICE_TYPE emofftype,
    SL.OFFICE_TYPE slemofftype,
    SL.STATUS
  FROM EMPLOYEE_MST em
  JOIN FA_SUBLEDGER_MST SL
  ON em.SL_CODE      =SL.SL_CODE
  WHERE em.OFFICE_ID<>SL.OFFICE_ID
  OR em.OFFICE_TYPE <>SL.OFFICE_TYPE
  AND em.OFFICE_TYPE!='DHB'
  AND SL.STATUS      ='A'
  ) t
SET t.sloffid   =t.emoffid
WHERE t.emoffid<>t.sloffid
OR t.emofftype <>t.slemofftype
AND t.emofftype!='DHB'
AND t.STATUS    ='A';
```

This returns those errors:

> SQL Error: ORA-01779: cannot modify a column which maps to a non key-preserved table
>   01779. 00000 -  "cannot modify a column which maps to a non key-preserved table"
>   *Cause:    An attempt was made to insert or update columns of a join view which map to a non-key-preserved table.
>   *Action:   Modify the underlying base tables directly.

And also this:

```
UPDATE FA_SUBLEDGER_MST
SET
  (
    OFFICE_ID,
    OFFICE_TYPE
  )
  =
  (SELECT OFFICE_ID,
    OFFICE_TYPE
  FROM EMPLOYEE_MST
  WHERE (FA_SUBLEDGER_MST.OFFICE_ID != EMPLOYEE_MST.OFFICE_ID
  OR FA_SUBLEDGER_MST.OFFICE_TYPE!  =EMPLOYEE_MST.OFFICE_TYPE)
  AND FA_SUBLEDGER_MST.SL_CODE      = EMPLOYEE_MST.SL_CODE
  AND EMPLOYEE_MST.OFFICE_TYPE!     ='DHB'
  ) ;
```

It worked but it updates all 124,451 rows, while the rows that met with the above specified condition are only 4,522 rows.

Both the tables contain more than 100,000 records and `OFFICE_ID` can be `1,2,3,4,5...18` and `OFFICE_TYPE` can be `'DE','DI','HO'`, Hence they repeat frequently.

I need a oracle query to do so. Can't use a procedure.

Would be thankful for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try MERGE instead of UPDATE. It is often faster and (in my opinion) more clear than UPDATE when updating a table based on another table

```
merge into FA_SUBLEDGER_MST s1
using (
    select SL_CODE, OFFICE_ID, OFFICE_TYPE
    from EMPLOYEE_MST
    where OFFICE_TYPE != 'DHB'
) emp
on (s1.SL_CODE = emp.SL_CODE)
when matched then update set 
    s1.OFFICE_ID = emp.OFFICE_ID,
    s1.OFFICE_TYPE = emp.OFFICE_TYPE
where sl.STATUS = 'A'
    and (s1.OFFICE_ID <> emp.OFFICE_ID
    or  s1.OFFICE_TYPE <> emp.OFFICE_TYPE);
```

Make sure that using-subquery doesn't return duplicate rows for each SL_CODE

Also your last example is missing the STATUS = 'A' condition

Comment: Sure, you can use WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN INSERT syntax, see: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/statements_9016.htm#SQLRF01606

Comment: @ypercube: Thanks but. The above query is giving this error: `Error at Command Line : 7 Column : 5
Error report -
SQL Error: ORA-00904: "SL"."SL_CODE": invalid identifier
00904. 00000 -  "%s: invalid identifier"`

The Table `FA_SUBLEDGER_MST` definitely contains `SL_CODE`.

Comment: And `SL_CODE` is **Primary Key** in `FA_SUBLEDGER_MST` and **Foreign Key** in `EMPLOYEE_MST`.

Comment: Changed sl -> s1, should fix ORA-00904. If SL_CODE is foreign key in EMPLOYEE_MST, you must make sure that the subquery returns one and only one row for each SL_CODE

Comment: @sjk: **Thanks**, It was stupid of me to notice that.
It worked on 2 of my databases, but didn't work on 3rd Database. I think there could be some errors in records contained in that database.
It gave error as: 
`Error report -
SQL Error: ORA-30926: unable to get a stable set of rows in the source tables
30926. 00000 -  "unable to get a stable set of rows in the source tables"
*Cause:    A stable set of rows could not be got because of large dml
           activity or a non-deterministic where clause.
*Action:   Remove any non-deterministic where clauses and reissue the dml.
1 row merged.`

Comment: There were only 10 rows that were to be Merged and contained around 70,000 records. Any Clue?